# Site to Site VPN with Cisco SA520

Tags: vpn, cisco, ipsec

I'm trying to make a site to site IPsec vpn tunnel between a cisco sa520 on my end and cisco enterprise device of the network I am connecting to. I am able to configure the device and get a tunnel established however I am unable to send any traffic from my system to any machine in the other network over the tunnel.

I checked the logs and it said:

> NAT-D not enabled

So I setup an alias for my WAN interface and also put a firewall rule that will show the alias as my external ip and push all LAN traffic from the router over the tunnel. However, when I ping the remote machine (the device in the other network which I am VPN'ing into) I get no response but I do see the Tx and Rx going over the tunnel. Also it still says NAT-D not enabled.

Am I missing something here? 
Do I need a VPN client on my machine to connect to my SA520 in order to send traffic over the tunnel or just having the system on the local lan is sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

you make site to site VPN , so there is no need for client , you have to exempt your VPN traffic from nating on outside interface , you can do this by configuring exempt nat and define your local network as source and remote network as Destination , if you provide more details on the network design and the device on the other end that will be helpfull